# Hibernate envers doesnt save deleted data in aud table

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I am using hibernate envers on spring boot have have these configs in application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=_AUDIT
```

I am deleting some records from base table, audit tables are created in db but deleted records doesnt show up in audit table or rev table.

How i am deleting records is by using this method :

```
 Query(value = "delete from basetable as a where a.first  <= :first and a.sev = :sev and a.id not in (select larm_id from roots as rca where larm_id = a.id)", nativeQuery = true)
    void delete(@Param("first") Long firstOccurrence, @Param("sev") int sev);

        repo.delete(1639835200L, 0);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is the fact you're performing a bulk delete.

The query that executes the delete could theoretically delete 0, 1, or multiple rows from the database and such a query does not cause Hibernate to load the entity state.  In short, you're effectively performing a JPA `CriteriaDelete` query which isn't supported.

If you want to  capture deleted state, you need to load the specific entity and delete that single instance of the entity, like:

```
MyEntity entity = entityManager.find( MyEntity.class, 123L );
entityManager.remove( entity );
```

Otherwise since Hibernate never loads the entity state, no event listeners get fired that provide the entity state to Envers so that it can be audited.